# Where did the Undock laptop option go in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, sleep, power

I recently upgraded from Windows 7 to 8.1 and have some trouble finding features. In Windows 7 under the Shutdown menu, there was an option to undock my laptop (as well as Sleep, Hibernate etc.).

Now some of these options (Sleep, Restart, Shutdown) moved to the Power button under the Settings menu. Switch User and Log out I can still find under in the dialog that pops up when I press F4 on the Desktop, but the undock option is missing completely. Even searching for Undock does not reveal the option.

Where did this option go?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly something got reverted when you upgraded, ie when you bought the laptop there was a specific manufacturer configuration which is now gone.

> **Undock** appears on the Shutdown Options menu only if the computer is **Advanced Configuration and Power Interface** (**ACPI**)-enabled and recognized as a portable computer in a docking station. If Undock does not appear on the Shutdown Options menu, your computer is not ACPI-enabled, or might not support undocking.

[Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754084.aspx)

The best thing to do would be to seek out **manufacturer drivers** for your laptop for 8.1, in order for it to be recognized properly and in order for Windows to give you the undock option back (**if Windows 8.1 even supports it, I couldn't find evidence that it does**)